# Within a Pandas dataset, how do I keep only the rows that have a minimum of 4 values, deleting the rest

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am using a pandas dataset and need to delete rows that have a value of 3 or less.  So if there are 12 columns and only 9 are populated with information that row needs to be deleted.

If this is confusing let me know and I will explain it another way.

Thanks good people

Edit

This is the code I have tried so far.  It gives a syntax error.

indexnames = dataset.row[<= 3].index

dataset.drop(indexnames, inplace=True)

Comment: What does this mean `So if there are 12 columns and only 9 are populated with information that row needs to be deleted`, how this sentence related to the first one?

Comment: It is explaining a situation where a row has 3 or less values. not a minimum of 4.

Comment: Would you like to post the code you have so far and perhaps a sample dataframe so we can see what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
New_df= Base_df.iloc[Base_df[Base_df.isnull().sum(axis=1)>3].index]
New_df
```